# configuring apache for accessing magento image folder through wamp virtualhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, wamp, virtualhost

I know there are many threads about this but after reading them all and trying many different configs, I can't seem to find the right formula for accessing an image folder of my magento website through a wamp virtualhost (403 Forbidden access on this server).

Error message :

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access
>   /app/design/frontend/default/template/page/slider/images/slide3.png on
>   this server.

My site is in

> c:/net generation/wamp/www/foodmeup

Loading the normal pages through my virtual host is not the problem, everything goes fine except for some custom images located in

> C:\Net
>   Generation\wamp\www\foodmeup\app\design\frontend\foodmeup\default\template\page\slider\images

My link to those image is for example `<img src="/app/design/frontend/default/template/page/slider/images/foodanalytics_groupe_mini.png"`

and the folder contains a .htaccess :

```
Order deny,allow
allow from all
```

my httpd-vhosts.conf is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
        DocumentRoot "c:/net generation/wamp/www/foodmeup" 
        ServerName foodmeup.local
        <Directory "c:/net generation/wamp/www/foodmeup">
             Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
             AllowOverride All
             Order deny,allow
             Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>  
        DocumentRoot "c:/net generation/wamp/www" 
        ServerName localhost
        ServerAlias 127.0.0.1
</VirtualHost>
```

my apache error log is

> [Mon Jun 16 10:35:09.410086 2014] [access_compat:error] [pid 5748:tid
>   1512] [client 127.0.0.1:53676] AH01797: client denied by server
>   configuration: C:/Net
>   Generation/wamp/www/foodmeup/app/design/frontend/default/template

After trying all kind of combinations, I just don't know what else to do, images located in this folder won't load because of permissions. Does anyone have a clue? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are getting a message from access_compat I assume you are using a Apache 2.4.x

You could try

a) fixing the security syntax and adding some to localhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    DocumentRoot "c:/net generation/wamp/www/foodmeup" 
    ServerName foodmeup.local
    <Directory "c:/net generation/wamp/www/foodmeup">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Order Allow,Deny
         Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>  
    DocumentRoot "c:/net generation/wamp/www" 
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias 127.0.0.1
    <Directory "c:/net generation/wamp/www">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Order Deny,Allow
         Deny from all
         Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Or

b) Using the Apache 2.4 syntax and adding some to localhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    DocumentRoot "c:/net generation/wamp/www/foodmeup" 
    ServerName foodmeup.local
    <Directory "c:/net generation/wamp/www/foodmeup">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>  
    DocumentRoot "c:/net generation/wamp/www" 
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory "c:/net generation/wamp/www">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Other than that there does not seem to be anything wrong.

**SECOND TRY**

Hang on, these 2 paths are not the same?? Is it as simple as that?

```
C:\Net Generation\wamp\www\foodmeup\app\design\frontend\foodmeup\default\template\page\slider\images

<img src="/app/design/frontend/default/template/page/slider/images/foodanalytics_groupe_mini.png"
```

Comment: thanks for your help! unfortunately, none of those solutions is working. I just can't understand. Is there some other config file I could share to help you understand the issue? the images were visible before switching to a virtual host... is there something to understand from the apache error log? (it does not state the entire path to the image folder)

Comment: ahhh, i'm so ashamed. thanks a lot, it's not the first time you're helping me!

Comment: No sweat, believe me we all do things like that.